# Is there a way to incorporate python code into moinmoin pages?

Tags: python, moinmoin

I was wondering whether there is a trick to (easily) incorporate some python code into a moinmoin page, perhaps by adding some [action](http://moinmo.in/HelpOnActions). The idea is that something like

```
<<<
for j in [1,3,5]:
   print(i)
>>>
```

is displayed on the page as

```
1
3
5
```

Quick and dirty is ok, safety is not a concern, I would like to have this for a stand-alone, "[desktop-mode](http://moinmo.in/DesktopEdition)" installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your moinmoin instance go to

```
data/macro
```

Make sure that there's an __init__.py with at least the following content:

```
from MoinMoin.util import pysupport

modules = pysupport.getPackageModules(__file__)
```

Then create your macro there:

```
touch PyShell.py
```

Use this as a template:

```
import StringIO
import sys

def macro_PyShell(macro, code):
  code_out = StringIO.StringIO()
  sys.stdout = code_out
  exec code.strip("'").strip('"')
  sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
  return macro.request.formatter.text(code_out.getvalue())
```

In your wiki-pages you should now be able to call that macro with:

```
<<PyShell("for i in [1,2,3]:\n  print i")>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To clarify, what I would like to be able to do is put some arbitrary small python code _in a page in edit mode_, and have some action/macro take my code, run it through the python interpreter, and display the output _on the page in viewing mode_.  Reading more into the documentation, I am thinking I should add a [parser](http://moinmo.in/HelpOnParsers).

Comment: I modified my macro example to fit your needs.

Comment: That looks pretty good! Shouldn't it be `exec` rather than `eval` though?

Comment: Yes you are right! I edited it a second before you mentioned :D

Comment: I tried it; inserting `<<PyShell("for i in [1,2,3]:\n  print i")>>` into the page indeed does call the code, however there is an error. The moinmoin log says: `return macro.request.formatter.text(exec(code)) "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"`

Comment: It works for a single command, such as `"print(10)"`, however in the case of e.g. `"for i in [1,2,3]:\n  print i"` there is an error: `execution failed [unexpected character after line continuation character]`

Comment: Stipping ' and/or " may be needed. That's it, is it?

Comment: I feel like this might be a massive security hole, if ever your wiki is exposed to the public.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach is to add a parser.

Below is a very quick and dirty adaptation of [Moinmoin's Hello World parser](http://moinmo.in/parser/HelloWorld.py).

```
import StringIO
import sys

class Parser():        

    def __init__(self, raw, request, **kw):
        self.raw = raw
        self.request = request
        self.kw=kw

    def format(self, formatter):       
        # Execute the code
        code_out = StringIO.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = code_out
        exec self.raw
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        out_lines = code_out.getvalue().split("\n")

        # Print the output
        for out_line in out_lines:
            self.request.write(formatter.rawHTML(out_line+"<br>"))
```

If it is saved for example as `path/to/MoinMoin/parser/interpret_python.py`, then you can enter into a page

```
{{{#!interpret_python
for j in [1,3,5]:
   print(j)
}}}
```

and it will produce the text

```
1
3
5
```

when viewing the page. Can be made safe(r) by confining the execution to a [sandbox](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython).